# What is the "right" midpoint rule for integrals?

Tags: calculus

I recently was helping a friend with calculus and they asked about the midpoint rule. I said:

> "I think I know what this will be. Given $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$,  Take $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{f(a+i/n)+f(a+(i+1)/n)}{2} \cdot\frac{b-a}{n}$$
>   which amounts to taking the midpoint between each of the sample heights, and calculating the sum as usual, which is the are of the trapezoid they form.

However, in the textbook she was using the midpoint rule was
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}f(a+.5/n+i/n)\frac{b-a}{n}$$

which, if I didn't mess up any indices just evaluates $f$ at the midpoint along the base of each "rectangle."

I've found references online (just google "midpoint rule") for both, but my question is *which is better?*

In particular,  can one be shown to be converge faster, at least in the sense of $O(n)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The midpoint rule sums up $f \left ( \frac{a_i+b_i}{2} \right )(b_i-a_i)$ for each subinterval $[a_i,b_i]$ of the partition. The trapezoidal rule sums up $\frac{f(a_i)+f(b_i)}{2}(b_i-a_i)$ for each subinterval $[a_i,b_i]$. If you ignore constant factors, then they have the same error bound.  If you include constant factors, then the midpoint rule has an error bound which is twice as good.

In any case, the bounds are proportional to a bound on the second derivative times $h^2$. The idea is to write $f(x)=f(m)+f'(m)(x-m)+\frac{1}{2} f''(\xi(x))(x-m)^2$ where $m$ is the midpoint and $\xi(x)$ is an unknown number between $x$ and $m$. If you exactly integrate the first two terms, you get the midpoint rule, so the error for the midpoint rule is given by the integral of the third term. The trapezoidal rule instead integrates $f(a)+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)$. So its error is given by the integral of the third term plus the integral of $g(x)= f(a) + \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)-(f(m)+f'(m)(x-m))$. This is a difference between a tangent line and a secant line; unsurprisingly its behavior is also related closely to the second derivative.

For actual errors in particular cases it really depends on the integrand. This derivation shows why: it entirely hinges on whether $\frac{1}{2} \int_a^b f''(\xi(x))(x-m)^2 dx$ and $\int_a^b f(a)+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)-f(m) dx$ have the same or opposite signs.